# Setting right coordinate system for northern Australia?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile, coordinate-system, australia

I have shapefile (points) which I got from adding xy data in ArcMap from Excel table. I had Latitude/Longitude data. It is area of northern Australia.

For example (5 points):

> Longitude
>   136.882
>   142.356
>   143.049
>   142.984
>   145.086
>
> Latitude
>   -12.249
>   -11.151
>   -12.659
>   -12.881
>   -15.135

What coordinate system should I define here and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Define Projection](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Define_Projection/001700000077000000/) tool.  You could define your shapefile as:

> GCS_WGS_1984 Datum: D_WGS_1984

OR

> GCS_Australian_1984 Datum: D_Australian_1984

Comment: I did like you said, but when I try to import it into postgis database it gives me error: ERROR:  Coordinate values are out of range [-180 -90, 180 90] for GEOGRAPHY type.

Comment: It might help to, when you are initially importing the xy data, to define the coordinate system then.

Comment: @againstflow, You should ask this as a seperate question since this question is different.  I do not have experience with postgis.  You can make reference to this question from your new question.  Include a postgis tag in your new question.

Comment: Good point @Casey, before importing the XY event layer define your dataframe with the coordinate system you want to define your layer to.

Comment: I tried that way, but it still gives me that error.

Comment: @againstflow, are you using x=longitude, y=latitude? If they're swapped, that could lead to that error message.

Comment: @artwork21, the points are split between Northern Territory and Queensland. NT didn't update to AGD84 so those could be in AGD66. But I think it's more likely they're in GDA94 or WGS84.

Comment: I reprojected in WGS84 in GRASS, and now there's no error! Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 2):

I took your data and plotted it using [WGS 1984](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System) (in the ArcMap Coordinate System menu under Predined > Geographic Coordinate Systems > World > WGS 1984), which, in most cases is a good world standard to go with when you don't know the source coordinate system.

[image: Australia data map]